# Using onesignal to catch up users who has unread chats

Tags: mobile, push-notification, backend, onesignal

Context:
We have chat in our e-commerce app between the sellers and buyers. Backend is just monolith golang server, which uses firebase push api to send notifications when someone messages.

There's a need for a solution, where I can track users and catchup with new push/sms those who has unread chats for more than 1hour, 12 hours, 1 day.
So, I was thinking to use onesignal journeys, for which I am planning to have a tag called `UnreadChatsCounts`

My question is:

I want to update this tag value each time new message is sent or when message was read, and based on this tag, create a journey map with several check point.
Do you think this solution is viable for a small server?

also, how it's possible to track in the journey the users who didn't open my first notification?

Thank you all in advance

- manually dumping list of unread users and sending sms's
- support team manually was writing to those sellers